# Openings vs 1. d4

Tags: opening, 1.d4

So, I played quite a bit a few years ago, at the 1500-1600 level, and now I'm getting back into things a bit.  I figured I'd use the chance to shore up my opening repertoire.

At the moment, I play 1. c4 as white and love it. I'm also pretty happy with the dragon as black vs e4.  Vs d4 though, I have issues.  I used to play the KID vs d4, but never really liked it. I like the fianchetto, but it was cramped in all the wrong ways, I never felt like I had good pawn breaks, and my minor pieces always were tripping over each other.  I like fianchetto positions in general. Before the English, I played a lot of KIA, and before the Dragon, Pirc.

So what should I look into vs d4 if I like the Dragon, and especially the English?

Answer (score 2):

Just as Brian Towers I would recommend you to give a look at the Grunfeld. The main difference with the KID is that you react faster in the center with *3...d5* and the resulting positions are often more open and "enjoyable" for your g7-bishop.
Other possibilities are the Benoni: play with c5 instead of e5 (in the KID) and with Queenside pawn play. Or the Benko Gambit which can lead to attacking positions with a dominant black square bishop (but depending on white's answer, the fianchetto won't always be the best option). In any case welcome back in the chess world and I wish you the best of luck with your black Dragon (a favorite of mine too)!!

Answer (score 1):

I would try the Gruenfeld in your position. It has the fianchetto without the cramping and has a lot of scope for someone who likes a tactical, non-symmetric counter-punching kind of game.

Answer (score 0):

I second Grunfeld & I can understand when you have an aficionado for the Dragon then you love fianchettoes but my suggestion would be that you can try Slav & Semi Slav as Black . If you see then their Winning percentages as Black is the Best against d4 . Kramnik Anand Kasparov are the best teachers in this Variation .

Technically what I feel that this opening has an Initiative which White cannot parry easily . I never feel that playing Black as Semi Slav & Slav has any disadvantage . lets go for an example now Lets consider the Semi Slav Meran Variation .

1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nf3 Nf6 4.Nc3 e6 5.e3 Nbd7 6.Bd3 dxc4 7.Bxc4 b5 8.Bd3 Bb7 9.O-O a6 10.e4 c5

You can see how Black snatches the initiative when he pushes the Bishop to d3 via 7)..b5 . It is Black infact who is dominating .

You can go through some games and you will find that whatever I mentioned would be an interesting option to you as well .